# robocopy run once

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am executing a `robocopy` command with my source on a and my destination is a local folder. However when `robocopy` runs and the server is down, it keeps repeating and retrying to find the folder every 30 seconds. I would like the `robocopy` to only run once, and return TRUE if succeeded and FALSE if it failed.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> `/r:<N>` Specifies the number of retries on failed copies. The default value of N is 1,000,000 (one million retries).

Run `robocopy source destination /r:0` to disable retries. Check the [exit code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954404) for the command status.